# Is there any reason I shouldn't serve the same page via http and https?

Tags: http, https

I have a site which serves public editorial content but also allows users to access private content after logging in.

Once a user is logged in, the private content is always accessed via https.

But what about the public content? Supposing I want to mix public and private content on the sama page (for example, if a user is logged in then I would like to add some personalised information to the standard public content pages). Is there any reason why I cannot serve the public content to a logged-in user via https, while still displaying it via http to non-identified users on public pages? And what are the technical implications of this?

Comment: The only reason to use http while having certificate on the server is to save time/resources spent by TLS handshake, which is performed once in a session.

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you just serve all your pages using https? I don't see any reason using http if you already have a ssl certificate.

Encryption wise I would say https is only necessary on your private pages, although I'm not really a expert.